# How do I duplicate a line or selection within Visual Studio Code?

Tags: editor, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Using Microsoft's Visual Studio Code, how do I duplicate a line of code and then move it up and down? (Similar to Sublime's <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> behaviour)

It's a feature that I use constantly, and am struggling using Visual Studio Code without it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duplicate line in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38727047/duplicate-line-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: I've also posted an answer here that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67620196/9868445 . It shows you how you can duplicate a __selection__, but it also does a bit more: Goes to the next line, and generates a print statement of that selection, in the active file's language.

Answer (score 1994, accepted):

The commands your are looking for are `editor.action.copyLinesDownAction` and `editor.action.copyLinesUpAction`.

You can see the associated keybindings by picking: *File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts*

**Windows:**

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>

**Mac:**

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd>

**Linux:**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>

(Might need to use numpad <kbd>Down</kbd> and <kbd>Up</kbd> for Linux)

Furthermore, commands `editor.action.moveLinesUpAction` and `editor.action.moveLinesDownAction` are the ones to move lines and they are bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> on Windows and Mac and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> on Linux.

Comment: And it seems `Alt+Up` or `Alt+Down` moves an existing line up and down. Nice

Comment: It's worth noting that the copyLines actions do not exist in the full Visual Studio, only Visual Studio Code.

Comment: **Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard**  in VS2015

Comment: Do you know how to "duplicate selection"? I couldn't find appropriate command :(

Comment: @nZeus For me it was the same `editor.action.copyLinesDownAction` I use for both duplicate line and selection.

Comment: That is not the same. In this case when you select a _line ending + full next line_ it will copy 2 lines (the whole first line, not just the \r\n). That's very annoying :(

Comment: @nZeus You can use https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rivenvirus.duplicatetext

Comment: Default `ctrl+shift+alt+down` didn't work for me on ubuntu. It worked though when reassigned to `ctrl+shift+d`.

Comment: On Linux `ctrl+shift+alt+down/up` only works for the num pad arrow keys.

Comment: That's copying the line, not duplicating it. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48208930/11343) for duplication :)

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-Alt-Down/Up not working on Ubuntu 17.10.1 - this works as a workplace shifter for Gnome.

Comment: `Ctrl-Shift-Alt-Down/Up` is such a painful shortcut for this common sortcut :( I liked `Ctrl-D` in  the Pycharm

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Down/Up will switch workspaces because Ctrl+Alt+Down/Up is use for switching workspaces in Ubuntu. Define your own shortcut

Comment: Notice that `Alt+Shift-Up/Down` in JSON documents doesn't position the comma correctly when moving-up a line at the end of the document.

Comment: i am using vscode 1.4 it (SHIFT + ALT + DOWN) is not working dear

Comment: i have selected one row text, now want to duplicate this in next / bottom row by keyboard, how can i do?

Comment: You can install 'IntelliJ IDEA Keybindings' extension, It will give you very useful other key bindings as well.

Comment: So in a Linux laptop without numpad the shortcut doesn't work.

Comment: CTRL+C and CTRL+V simpler on linux (

Comment: Oddly, on Linux, `Add Cursor Above` and `Add Cursor Below` had two keybindings. One of which was the default Windows shortcut for `Copy Line Up / Down`. Not sure what the practical purpose of **When `!editorReadonly`** was, but I've reassigned the keybinding to have the same shortcut on Linux as Windows.

Comment: In 2021, Ubuntu 20.04, only the Ctrl+Shift+Alt NumPad Up Down worked.

Comment: there is a new command as @Seralto answered called `editor.action.duplicateSelection`

Comment: The keybindings suggested in this answer do not duplicate the selected code "Similar to Sublime's cmd+shift+d behaviour."  The VSCode "Copy Line Down" shortcut duplicates entire lines of code, which means you can't use it to easily duplicate an "else if" block. It also doesn't duplicate inline selected text(!?), which means you can use it to duplicate individual properties inside an HTML attribute.

Comment: If by any chance, anyone here's using regular Visual Studio instead of Visual Studio Code, I found `Edit.Duplicate` which clones a line perfectly. Combined with Alt + Cursor down to get what you want.

Answer (score 231):

You can find keyboard shortcuts from

> File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts

Default Keyboard Shortcuts are,

*Copy Lines Down Action* : <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd>

*Copy Lines Up Action*   :   <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>

*Move Lines Up Action*   :   <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>

*Move Lines Down Action*   :   <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd>

Or you can override the keyboard shortcuts from

> File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts

And editing the `keybindings.json`

*Example:*

```json
[
  {
      "key": "ctrl+d",
      "command": "editor.action.copyLinesDownAction",
      "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
      "key": "ctrl+shift+up",
      "command": "editor.action.moveLinesUpAction",
      "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
      "key": "ctrl+shift+down",
      "command": "editor.action.moveLinesDownAction",
      "when": "editorTextFocus"
  }
]
```

Comment: Also, if you have to move a line far, ctrl+C and ctrl+X will easily copy/cut the current line without having to select it. And `ctrl + L` (command **expandLineSelection**) will select a line. Repeating ctrl + L selects additional lines making a block select easy. Or you can make a rough block select with mouse and then ctrl+L to include the ends.

Comment: Sadly there is nothing at all in default PDF with list of the shortcuts about Alt+Shift+up/down... Not quite true, it is mentioned "Multi cursor and selection" section with "Insert cursor above/below" action!

Comment: I just add my own `ctrl+D` and remove the conflict other shortcut.

Answer (score 103):

It miss an answer to this question, **"How to duplicate selection of code"** Similar to Sublime's <kbd>cmd</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> or Jetbrains' <kbd>cmd</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> behaviour.

Install plugin **Duplicate selection or line** from VS Code Marketplace

[image: Duplicate selection or line VS Code plugin]

This extension provides bindings for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> (Windows/Linux) and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> (MacOS). To customize keyboard shortcuts **Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts:**

```json
{
  "mac": "cmd+d",
  "key": "ctrl+d",
  "command": "geeebe.duplicateText",
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

**Note :** The shortcut does also the duplicate line so if you install it, remove your previous <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> shortcut on `copyLinesDownAction` (if you did it before) otherwise duplicate selection can bug.

Comment: I was frustrated by "copy lines down" shortcut which did not exactly behave like Sublime Text/Intellij Ctrl+D feature (it copied the entire lines instead of just the selection). Thanks for pointing out this plugin!

Comment: I was about to ditch vscode and install atom, but this extension has prevented me. the default duplicate functionality of vscode is not up to the mark. atom is so much better in this regard.

Comment: This is the most helpful answer!!

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04: I set *copy line down* to ctrl-shift-d and it works like in Atom. (Remove it from showing run and debug first.)

Comment: Install it with Ctrl+P, `ext install geeebe.duplicate`
Unfortunately the extension isn't yet available for VSCodium. Issue with request [here](https://github.com/gregbacchus/vscode-duplicate/issues/3)

Answer (score 39):

In VScode, they call this `Copy Line Up` and `Copy Line Down`

From the menu, go to:

> File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts

Check already assigned keyboard shortcut for this, or adjust yours.

Sometimes the default assigned shortcut may not work, mostly because of OS.

In my Ubuntu, I adjusted this to: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Not _quite_ the same, but an interesting hidden feature nonetheless. Why is this not in the menu?

Answer (score 36):

In **VSCode** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> duplicates the whole line below.

I prefer this to the accepted answer, because it only requires one hand to do this and feels way more natural.

The accepted answer will probably do it for most people, however <kbd>Down</kbd> sits the other side of the keyboard. 
So you have two options, use both hands on (Left Hand:<kbd>L Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L Alt</kbd>+ Right Hand:<kbd>Up/Down</kbd>), or with a single hand use the right <kbd>R Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd>. The second option feels weird in my opinion. I'd rather use the option where my hand naturally sits on the keyboard, and if its one hand, even better.

Comment: The main issue with that is you loose what was on your clipboard

Comment: This answer has been broken with the 2023 May release of vscode

Answer (score 27):

Try <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd>/<kbd>DOWN</kbd>

It worked for me!

Answer (score 27):

- For **Jetbrains IDE Users** who migrated to **VSCode**.
- Install(Anyone):

1. JetBrains IDE Keymap: [Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=isudox.vscode-jetbrains-keybindings)
2. vscode-intellij-idea-keybindings [Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.intellij-idea-keybindings) `(Preferred)`

- Use this `Intellij Darcula Theme`:  [Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=trinm1709.dracula-theme-from-intellij)
- The keymap has covered most of keyboard shortcuts of VS Code, and makes VS Code more '**JetBrains IDE like**'.
- Above extensions imports keybindings from JetBrains to VS Code. After installing the extension and restarting VS Code you can use VS Code just like **IntelliJ IDEA, Webstorm, PyCharm**, etc.

Comment: Just the JetBrains IDE Keymap extension is required. This gives you the familiar `ctrl`-`D` shortcut.

Comment: Help me alot. Thanks buddy.

Comment: it asks me for 15 chars, but what I want to say: "Bro"

Answer (score 20):

Simply go to the file -> preferences -> keyboard shortcuts
There you can change any shortcut you like. search for duplicate and change it to whatever you always use in other editors. I changed to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: Absolutely my thought right now. I tried the accepted answer on linux and it simply did NOT work. Editing your own shortcuts is a great practice and a new start for a better future. CTRL + D is the most intuitive and easy shortcut command for this. Why .....why...... CTRL + SHIFT + ALT + .. please stop, my computer almost shut down and reset after doing this.

Comment: The Command you need to change in the Keyboard shortcuts list is called: `Duplicate Selection` `(editor.action.duplicateSelection)`

Answer (score 18):

For **Windows** :

To Copy Up - <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>

To Copy Down - <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd>

For **mac** :

To Copy Up - <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>

To Copy Down - <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd>

For **linux** :

To Copy Up - <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>

To Copy Down - <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>

**Note** : You may change your keyboard shortcuts keybinding for visual studio code
by pressing **<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>**, then **type open keyboard shortcut** in the pallet and then hit enter
so new file will be opened **(Key board shortcut file)** 
you can see all the shortcuts over their and can change keybindings by clicking twice over the respective keybinding and then by entering your own keybinding, finally hit enter.

Hope this will help somebody!

Comment: NONE of these suggestions work with `VS Ccode 1.49.2` (`Electron` 9.2.1, `Chrome` 83.0.4103.122, `Node.Js` 12.14.1, `Linux` 5.11.0-36-generic).  I wonder with `VS Code` if it can sometimes be a moving target.

Answer (score 15):

Note that for Ubuntu users (<= 17.4), Unity uses <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow Key</kbd> for moving programs across virtual workspaces, which conflicts with the VS Code shortcuts. You'll need to rebind `editor.action.copyLinesDownAction` and `editor.action.copyLinesUpAction` to avoid the conflict (or change your workspace keybindings).

For Ubuntu 17.10+ that uses GNOME, it seems that GNOME [does not use this keybinding in the same way](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-workspaces-movewindow.html.en) according to its documentation, though if someone using vanilla workspaces on 17.10 can confirm this, it might be helpful for future answer seekers.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 19.10 and Ctrl+Alt+Down still moves between workspaces.

Comment: To change your workspace keybindings, tested on Ubuntu 22.04, run in your terminal: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-down "[]" && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-up "[]" && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "[]" && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "[]"`

Answer (score 13):

Duplicate line: <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>△</kbd>/<kbd>▽</kbd>

Move line up/down: <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>△</kbd>/<kbd>▽</kbd>

Answer (score 11):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> press these keys together not separate for windows

Answer (score 9):

**Problem**

There seems to be a problem with the original "duplicate line down" shortcut on Ubuntu, mostly due to a conflict with an already existing workspace related shortcut on the operating system.

**Workaround**

However, an easy workaround is to simply <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (copies the entire line) and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (pastes the copied line on to a new one)... Effectively, giving you the same end result.

Comment: this shoud be the correct answer since it works out of the box in vscode vanilla

Comment: Confirmed on WSL2, I don't wish to modify any keyboard mapping so this works a treat

Answer (score 9):

This keymap will **duplicate the current line** if nothing is selected or **duplicate the selected words**.

1. Access:

   **File/Preferences/Keyboard shortcuts**
2. In the right top corner, click on **Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)**.
3. Insert this keymap:

   ```json
   {
     "key": "shift+alt+d",
     "command": "editor.action.duplicateSelection"
   }
   ```
4. Use **alt+arrows up/down** to move the line (Default behaviour of VS Code).

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Coming from sublime text this is invaluable!

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for. Same as in Notepad++ or Sublime. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

In MacOS I usually use:

- Copy line above `shift` + `option` + `↑`
- Copy line bellow `shift` + `option` + `↓`

Comment: With this command, you are only able to duplicate the whole line, its not possible to duplicate just selected text one

Answer (score 8):

If you coming from Sublime Text and do not want to relearn new key binding, you can use this extension for Visual Code Studio.

> Sublime Text Keymap for VS Code
>
> This extension ports the most popular Sublime Text keyboard shortcuts to Visual Studio Code. After installing the extension and restarting VS Code your favorite keyboard shortcuts from Sublime Text are now available.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.sublime-keybindings

Answer (score 6):

I rebound the **Duplicate Selection** keybind (`editor.action.duplicateSelection`) to Ctrl+D, this duplicates the line if nothing is selected or duplicates the current selection if there is.

To open the keyboard shortcuts menu, go to `File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts` or press Ctrl+K then Ctrl+S.

Answer (score 3):

For Fedora 29 workstation (Gnome 3.30.2) and Ubuntu users.

Unbind unnecessary left/right workspace keyboard combinations, list them by terminal

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep -E "org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-|org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-"
```

Unbind them

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "[]"
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "[]"
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-left "[]"
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-right "[]"
```

Reset duplicate shortcuts

- Super+Pgdown/PgUp , Ctrl+Alt+DownArrow/UpArrow
- Super+Shift+PgDown/PgUp , Ctrl+Alt+Shift+DownArrow/UpArrow

They can be easily reset to work with only one shortcut in Settings>Devices>Keyboard
Only type again Super+PgUp for "Move to workspace above" as an example.

[image]

Now with less duplicate shortcuts in fedora29 all [vscode shortcuts for linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf) must work fine

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 22.04 although it was "move-to-workspace-down" and "move-to-workspace-up" that I had to modify to get VS Code copy line up/down to work. Annoyingly it doesn't look like you can modify them in the UI but this CLI seems to do it. Thanks muchly!

Comment: Single command for Ubuntu 22.04: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-down "[]" && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-up "[]" && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "[]" && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "[]"`

Answer (score 2):

Direct line duplication (without the clipboard step) is proposed by the [Contextual Duplicate](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lafe.contextualduplicate) extension.

It is mapped on <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

For Linux users: I noticed what on Linux you quite an often need to use <kbd>win</kbd> key. For Windows combo is:
<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd>  + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd>

then for Linux is same just add <kbd>win</kbd> key:
<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd>  + <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd>

I noticed that in a few combos now. Say <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd>  + <kbd>L</kbd> locks Linux, but <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>win</kbd>  + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> for Intellij formats code. Under Windows is just <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd>  + <kbd>L</kbd> to format the code.

Comment: I like this solution for ubuntu users. I am using ubuntu 20.04 and I had trouble using the others approaches.

Answer (score 2):

### For those migrating from WebStorm/PhpStorm,

You could install **[IntelliJ IDEA Keybindings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.intellij-idea-keybindings)** to keep using almost all the keyboard shortcuts as you did in Webstorm/Phpstorm.

So,

- Duplicate lines => <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
- Move a line/selection of code Up/Down => <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>UP</kbd>/<kbd>DOWN</kbd>

---

Also, here is a list of **[recommended VS Code extensions](https://digitalfortress.tech/tutorial/moving-from-webstorm-phpstorm-to-vs-code/)** that will make your transition from WebStorm/Phpstorm much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> (Up Arrow or Down Arrow)

Answer (score 1):

To duplicate SELECTION within Visual Studio Code (Similar to Sublime's ctrl+shift+d behaviour) you have to setup a shortcut in preferences.

For windows:
Open File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.
In the opened tab, search for "Duplicate Selection" and press the edit button in the first column for binding key combination.

Answer (score -2):

in my last version Visual Studio Code 1.30.2
it wil be change automatically into

---

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: In vscode this highlights the word under the cursor. Perhaps Notepad++ used the ctrl+D shortcut. Just going from memory.

Comment: Yes, Ctrl+D is definitly "Add Next Occurrence". Not something that you'd be using all that often to need a shortcut, and D is a bad mnemonic for it anyway, so VS-Code could just move it and bind Ctrl+D to Duplicate Selection.