# Duplicate line in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to find the shortcut for duplicating a line in Visual Studio Code (I am using 1.3.1) I tried the obvious <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ctrl+D for line duplication is not that obvious: it works in Notepad++ for example, but it *deletes* the current line in Eclipse :)

Comment: See the [Contextual Duplicate](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lafe.contextualduplicate) extension

Comment: by default ,`CTRL + D` just select the next occurrence that was selected vs other IDEs .

Comment: @kol Having used Visual Studio previously, and VSCode being MS product I would assume that VSCode inherits a lot of things from it. CTRL+D works fine in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: TheWebGuy, please make more clear/obvious whether you want the clipboard content to survive. It seems implicitly obvious to me that you want that, but some of the answer authors seem of a different opinion. And without you being explicit about this, it is hard to convince them (and voters) that the answer is between unhelpful and wrong.

Comment: For ubuntu 20+ use  `CTRL + SHIFT + ALT + 2`

Answer (score 671, accepted):

The default is:

- Windows / Linux <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>
- Mac <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>OPTION</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>

To change it, click **File** > **Preferences** > **Keyboard Shortcuts**:

[image]

Search for `copyLinesDownAction` or `copyLinesUpAction` in your keyboard shortcuts

---

Update for Ubuntu:

It seems that Ubuntu is hiding that shortcut from being seen by VSCode (i.e. it uses it probably by its own). There is an issue about that on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6197).

In order to work in Ubuntu you will have to define your own shortcut, e.g. to copy the line using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> you could use a `keybindings.json` like this:

```
[
    { "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+j", "command": "editor.action.copyLinesDownAction",
                                    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly" },
    { "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+k", "command": "editor.action.copyLinesUpAction",
                                    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly" }
]
```

Comment: On Mac: Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts. Shift+Option+Down Arrow.

Comment: @DAXaholic answer was correct if you need even simple solution just keep the cursor on line which you want to duplicate and press ctrl+c and ctrl+v. it works fine

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, by default, the ```Ctrl``` + ```Shift``` + ```Up Arrow``` / ```Down Arrow``` shortcuts are mapped to moving windows to different workspaces. You can change this in ```Ubuntu -->System Settings --> Keyboard --> Shortcuts --> Navigation``` then press ```Backspace``` to delete the unwanted shortcuts.

Comment: Mine is bound to Ctrl+Shift+Alt+DownArrow, but it doesn't actually do anything when I click those buttons.

Comment: for ubuntu according to Mwiza answer Ctrl + Shift + Alt + ↓

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 it's `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Shift` + `Numpad 2` / `Numpad 8`.

Comment: This is an annoying default shortcut for two reasons. First, I always inadvertently hit it when doing multicursor selection (which defaults to Shift + Alt with a mouse but for some reason Shift + _Ctrl_ + Alt with arrow keys). Second, it is hard to hit when right hand is on the mouse which is often the case when you've just copied something from the browser which is when you'd use this over Ctrl+C Ctrl+V to begin with.

Comment: Isn't is easier to just not select anything, ```ctrl```+```c``` / ```ctrl```+```v```? It just copies the whole line and pastes it below.

Answer (score 236):

The duplicate can be achieved by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> with cursor in the line without nothing selected.

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but I would imagine this isn't acceptable for the OP as this copies the line into the clipboard, which is one very good reason to want a "duplicate line" command instead of a copy / paste command.

Comment: This does not work if `editor.emptySelectionClipboard` option is set to `false` (my preferred configuration).

Comment: This blows away what I had in my clipboard

Comment: One interesting this  thing I noted in this method is , no need to release Ctrl Key after pressing 'C' (  Release only after releasing V)

Comment: This ruins the whole purpose of instant line duplication.

Comment: Windows 10 has built-in clipboard history; `Win+V`

Comment: r u kidding me?
if u copy a line form any where and this time need to duplicate a line you clipboard will be overwrite and u missed ur data!

Answer (score 175):

You can use the following depending on your OS:

**Windows:**

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>↓</kbd>    or
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>↑</kbd>

**Mac:**

<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>  or
<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>

**Linux:**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> or
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>

**Note**: For some linux distros use Numpad arrows

Comment: That is mapped to GNOME workspace switcher unfortunately on Ubuntu :-(

Comment: This works in 2022 thanks, it is shift + alt not ctrl

Answer (score 39):

**Ubuntu :**

- Duplicate Line Up : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +
  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>
- Duplicate Line Down : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +
  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>

Comment: This is actually a good solution (working on Ubuntu 20 & 19) that does not require any changes to the default setting.
Might not seem very intuitively but 8 & 2 are actual Up and Down in the NumPad

Comment: Default options didn't work for me on Ubuntu 20... neither the keys that you showed here then I went to "File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts then editor.action.copyLinesDownAction" changed the Ctrl + Alt + Shift + ArrowDown (default) to Ctrl + Alt + NumPad2 and worked fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 33):

These are the default settings:

**Windows:**

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>

**macOS:**

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>OPTION</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>OPTION</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>

However, if you want to duplicate the line with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, then you have to modify the **keyboard shortcuts** of your VS Code.

**Windows:**

**File** > **Preferences** > **Keyboard shortcuts**

**macOS:**

**Manage** > **Keyboard shortcuts**

and search for **`Copy Line Down`**. From there add <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or your desired key combination.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Use the following: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>+(<kbd>↓</kbd> or <kbd>↑</kbd>)

Comment: This is the BEST answer in my opinion, and is exactly what I was looking for.  It sure would be nice if there were just "Universal" standards for keyboard shortcuts that *everybody* who desires to build a reputable product could adhere to.  Then, eventually, it would be as commonly understood as "Ctrl-C" which is even typed on keyboards.  Why can't we have about 26*3 == 78 universally standardized keyboard shortcuts in the world?  26 for "Ctrl", 26 for "Ctrl+Shift", 26 for "Alt".  Then, if products/tools want more than the 78 standard shortcuts, add "Alt+Shift", "Ctrl+Alt+Shift" etc. ? :-)

Answer (score 14):

Search for `copyLinesDownAction` or `copyLinesUpAction` in your keyboard shortcuts

Usually, it is <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>

Answer (score 12):

There is a new command in v1.40: `editor.action.duplicateSelection` unbound to any keybinding.

> **Duplicate selection**
>
> We have added a new action named Duplicate Selection. When executed,
>   the current selection will be duplicated and the result will be
>   selected. When there is no selection, the current line will be
>   duplicated, all without writing to the system clipboard.

from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_40.md

Some may find it helpful in certain situations.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to create keybindings that are only active when Vim for VSCode is on and in a certain mode (i.e., "Normal", "Insert", or "Visual").

To do so, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open up VSCode's Command Palette, then search for "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)"--selecting this option will open up **keybindings.json**. Here, custom bindings can be added.

For example, here are the classic VSCode commands to move/duplicate lines tweaked for ease of use in Vim..

```
    [
      {
        "key": "alt+j",
        "command": "editor.action.moveLinesDownAction",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && vim.mode == 'Normal'"
      },
      {
        "key": "alt+shift+j",
        "command": "editor.action.copyLinesDownAction",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && vim.mode == 'Normal'"
      },
      {
        "key": "alt+k",
        "command": "editor.action.moveLinesUpAction",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && vim.mode == 'Normal'"
      },
      {
        "key": "alt+shift+k",
        "command": "editor.action.copyLinesUpAction",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && vim.mode == 'Normal'"
      },
    ]
```

Now we can use these Vim-friendly commands in VSCode!

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to move a line down
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to move a line up
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to duplicate a line down
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to duplicate a line up

Comment: I would suggest to change the condition `vim.mode == 'Normal'` to `vim.mode != 'Insert'` so that these shortcuts also work when having a visual selection.

Answer (score 2):

Though there are some right answers already here, I always forget shortcuts in different IDEs and Text Editors especially switching between Windows and Linux.

In Windows VSCode v1.77.3, I've just found that Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V works perfect and easy to remember:

1. Set cursor on the line you want to duplicate. (Don't select anything)
2. Ctrl+C
3. Ctrl+V (press as many as the line count you want to get)

Comment: Completely unintuitive... but works!

Answer (score 1):

Another 2 very usefull shortcuts are to move lines selected up and down, like sublime text does...

```
{
  "key" : "ctrl+shift+down", "command" : "editor.action.moveLinesDownAction",
  "when" : "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
},
```

and

```
{
  "key" : "ctrl+shift+up", "command" : "editor.action.moveLinesUpAction",
  "when" : "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```

Comment: Wrong. You don't need to `select` a line in ST in order to duplicate it.

Comment: shortcuts are to move "lines" selected

Answer (score 1):

VC Code Version: 1.22.2, Mac.

- Go to: Code -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts (cmd + K; cms + S);
- Change (edit): "Add Selection To Next Find Match": "cmd + what you want". For me this is "cmd + D" and I pur cmd + F;
- Go to "Copy Line Down": "cmd + D". You can edit this and set cmd + D for example

Answer (score 0):

Update that may help Ubuntu users if they still want to use the <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> instead of another set of keys.

I just installed a fresh version of VSCode on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I had duplicate commands for `Add Cursor Above` and `Add Cursor Below`

[Original Keybindings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rGwD.png)

I just removed the bindings that used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and added my own with the following

`Copy Line Up`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>

`Copy Line Down`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>

[New Keybindings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teJCF.png)

Answer (score 0):

To copy the current line without selection, <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> will do the trick. For those of you who have vim enabled on VSCode, you will need to ensure that the following is set:

```
"vim.overrideCopy": false
```

Answer (score -3):

**Windows:**

Duplicate Line Down : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: For me, this triggers the built-in debugger.