# VSCode - Shortcut to copy Current Line

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is the shortcut to copy current line in VSCode?

I know we can `Ctrl+L` to select the line then `Ctrl+C` to copy. But is there any better solution. For example, in Geany, we can `Ctrl+Shift+C` to copy the line where the cursor is.

To be clear I am not talking about [Duplicate line in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38727047/duplicate-line-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Just press the `Ctrl + C` without selection it'll copy entire line and you can past it wherever you wanted

Comment: @BhargavTailor how am I supposed to close this question?

Comment: Stackoverflow don't have the close option but you can delete the question from you profile or you can flow the explaination to mark your question closed from the this link: https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/32435/11/11_chapter%203.pdf

Comment: @BhargavTailor or you can give the answer and I can accept it.

Comment: @BhargavTailor After all years of vs code how did I missed that...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here is your solution for your problem

Just press the **Ctrl + C** without selection it'll copy entire line and you can past it wherever you wanted,

Please read below solution for the query you ask in your question's comment

Stackoverflow don't have the close option but you can delete the question from you profile or you can follow the explaination to mark your question closed from the below link:

[How to Closed Questions on StackOverflow?](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ukf3hioqFurPPuYmRsNq_5eHOgWgCzrD/view)

Comment: cmd + c on mac copies the current line thanks for this useful info

Comment: If this doesn't work, you might have disabled the "Editor: Empty Selection Clipboard" option

Comment: Wow, surprised I hadn't noticed this. So simple!

Answer (score 22):

Another alternative to the accepted answer that I often use is <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>DOWN</kbd> which duplicates the current line to the line below (likewise, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>UP</kbd> duplicates to the line above).  Once you get the copy of your line you can use <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>UP</kbd>/<kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>DOWN</kbd> to move it wherever you want.  This works well if you are wanting a copy of the line in the near vicinity of the current line.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Go to **File ==> Preferences ==> Keyboard Shortcuts**, and update the copy line shortcut entry with any combination you like.for example **Ctrl + DownArrow** is good for me.

[image]

Comment: I have edited the question to show the image. However, this is a wrong answer. The question explicitly says "To be clear I am not talking about [Duplicate line in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38727047/duplicate-line-in-visual-studio-code)"

Comment: Thanks, i was in a hurry, it seems that i haven't read the rest of the post .