# What is the shortcut in Visual Studio Code for console.log

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to know what is the shortcut for `console.log` in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: I've just created this extension, 2 seconds and you'd have a console.log shortcut:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EylonShmilovich.easy-log-js :)

Answer (score 372, accepted):

**Update Feb, 2019:**

As suggested by [Adrian Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7384648/adrian-smith) and others: If you want to bind a keyboard shortcut to create a console log statement, you can do the following:

1. *File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts*
2. Above the search bar on the right you'll see this icon [image] Click on it. (*When hovered over it it says: Open keyboard shortcuts (JSON)*
3. Add this to the JSON settings:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+l",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "console.log('${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}$1')$2;"
  }
}
```

Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will output the console snippet. Also, if you already have text selected it will be put inside the log statement.

---

*If you rather want intellisene/autocomplete:*

Go to *Preferences* -> *User Snippets* -> Choose *Typescript* (or whatever language you want) or a 'Global Snippet File' depending on your need. A `json` file should open. You can add code snippets there.

There is already a snippet for `console.log` commented out:

```
"Print to console": {
    "scope": "javascript,typescript,javascriptreact",
    "prefix": "log",
    "body": [
        "console.log('$1');",
        "$2"
    ],
    "description": "Log output to console"
}
```

You used to have to do this for every language, but now in the 'Global Snippet File' you can set the `scope` property which allows you to explicitly declare multiple languages.

Should you need the exact name of the language: check it by clicking the `Select Language Mode` button in the right side of the VS Code bottom toolbar. It will prompt you to select a language at the top and in the process will show the JSON name of the language in parenthesis, which you can enter in the snippet file as in the example above.

---

Also, you should set `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"`, so your snippets appear above intellisense. Thanks @Chris!

You can find snippet suggestions in *Preferences -> Settings -> Text Editor -> Suggestions*

Comment: This used to work, but it doesn't anymore, since last update maybe? Is it just me?  https://s17.postimg.org/5mxnx4umn/2017_02_14_11h10_03.jpg

Comment: The above defined prefix is "log" so typing "c" will not help ;) Start typing "l" instead.

Comment: Oh, i forgot to mention i had it changed to work with "c". I didn't change anything, and after update it's not working anymore. Don't have the snippet anymore, but this `"prefix": "c",` should make it work with "c" right?

Comment: If everything else is correct. Yes. Note that you also require to add the snippet to *each* language you want to use it. So if you added it to TS it will not work in JS, vice versa.

Comment: Here is the new proof with using `"prefix" :"c"` inside a js file https://s23.postimg.org/a8xwzsbrv/2017_02_14_12h16_00.jpg Can you confirm that is working with you?

Comment: Yes. But it is the last entry in a very long list.

Comment: How can i make the snippet to be first in the suggestion list? in my env, when i type log i get "log" of another lib and only then i see the snippet i just created.

Comment: See answer below :) "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"

Comment: You can alternatively click on the `{}` button beside the search bar to open the `keybindings.json` file -- Easiest way as I was not able to see the _"For advanced customizations open and edit keybindings.json"_ message!

Comment: Thanks. This was extremely useful. Here is my version using the clipboard, and adding a quick tag made up of the clipboard with all non-alphanumeric characters removed as an identifier incase there are multiple items logged: `"snippet": "console.log(\"${CLIPBOARD/[^0-9^a-z]//gi}\", ${CLIPBOARD}$1);"`

Comment: This did not work for me on Mac VSCode 1.64.2

Comment: this answer should start with 'intellisene/autocomplete' -> much better approach then keybindings.

Comment: I've just created this extension, 2 seconds and you'd have a console.log shortcut:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EylonShmilovich.easy-log-js :)

Answer (score 216):

All the above answers works fine, but if you don't want to change the configuration of the visual studio code, rather want auto-completion for `console.log(object);`
you can simply use this shortcut **clg** and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for suggestion and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Note** : *This feature is avaliable when you **install JavaScript (ES6) code snippets** extension.*

Similarly you have auto-completion for :

- **clg** for `console.log(object);`
- **clo** for `console.log('object :', object);`
- **ccl** for `console.clear(object);`
- **cer** for `console.error(object);`
- **ctr** for  `console.trace(object);`
- **clt** for `console.table(object);`
- **cin** for `console.info(object);`
- **cco** for `console.count(label);`

  (This list continues...)
  Also, Another great extension in this regard is [Turbo Console Log](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChakrounAnas.turbo-console-log). I'm personally using both of these on my daily basis and enjoy their combination.

---

References:

1. link for JavaScript(ES6) code snippets :

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xabikos.JavaScriptSnippets

[image]

2. Preview from Visual Studio Code:

[image]

Comment: Perfect. +1. This is what I was looking for -- not to have to make any config changes.

Comment: No need to press `ctrl+space`. Suggestion appear without that.

Comment: This is the best answer and very helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: clg - always work for me from JavaScript (ES6) code snippets, but now I get - 
ChannelMergerNode after clg !??? 
Thanks for Turbo Console )

Answer (score 93):

Type `log` and hit `enter`. It will auto-complete `console.log();`

Comment: I seem to have a bug where typing `log` and pressing enter only outputs `console.log();` on some occasions, and I can't figure out why? Is it just me or can others type `log` then enter and get a consistent `console.log();` output every time?

Comment: You have to wait a few milisenconds / seconds for the command line to regonise what you have typed. sometimes it laggs a bit

Comment: @BenClarke when you type the log, look the right-side for the texts that are coming. There are several options for the log and you need to choose the correct one for the console print. I suggest using the ES6 code snippets as answered above.

Comment: This only works in some situations. I have a few packages installed that export a `log` function, so it wants to autocomplete to those. Used to work for me, but now it's not consistent. I too suggest @sanbukar's answer

Answer (score 49):

The top answer by @Sebastian Sebald is perfectly fine, but hitting a similar problem (not console.log specifically, but rather it "missing") I wanted to also contribute an answer.

Your prefix is indeed working - by default its `log` and in your case you have changed it to `c`. When you type `log` (or `c`) VSCode will generate a full list of "all the things™" based on many factors (ie I don't know what factors, probably class relevance).

Things like snippets tend to gravitate towards the bottom. To bump them to the top, despite their length, add this to your settings:

```
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"
```

Comment: You're the hero I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Haha no worries at all

Comment: I get an error saying `Property editor.snippetSuggestions  is not allowed` though, what is that about?

Comment: @Bossan     `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"` should be placed in the settings.json file (`ctrl+shift+p` and type `user settings`) Alternatively, you can search for this property in the general user settings (Preferences > Settings) and use the dropdown menu to change it to `top`.

Comment: You deserve a medal

Answer (score 26):

In Atom there is a nice shortcut for console.log() and I wanted the same in VS Code.

I used the solution by [@kamp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46660473) but it took me a while to figure out how to do it.
Here are the steps I used.

1. Go to: File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts
2. At the top of the page you will see a message that says:
   **For advanced customizations open and edit keybindings.json**

[image: Click on link]

3. This opens two panes: the default keybindings, and your custom bindings.

[image: Enter code in right pane]

4. Enter the code provided by [@kamp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46660473)

Answer (score 23):

Other way is to open *keybindings.json* file and add your desired key combination. In my case it's:

```
{
    "key": "cmd+shift+l",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "console.log($1)$0;"
    }
}
```

Comment: "ctrl+shift+c" for the "key" is a bit easier to click with one hand IMO and its not already taken by another keybinding if your using the default vs code keybindings

Answer (score 17):

Anyone looking for ***For advanced customizations open and edit keybindings.json***

[image]

Click this little icon to open keybindings.json.

Use this code for generate both console.log() & to generate console.log("Word") for selected text.

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+l",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "console.log('${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}$1')$2;"
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, on mac had to go to code->preferences->keyboard shorcuts and than click on that button, than put the {...} inside the array.

Comment: thanks man, someone should update the accepted answer so everyone else can skip 10 mins searching

Comment: U Saved a lot of Time Man !! Thanks

Comment: This isn't there on my mac. I needed to do cmd+shift+p and then search for keyboard shortcuts (JSON)

Answer (score 12):

When you type the word **log**, you will see something like this:

[image: Choosing the method that says Log to the console]

Choose the one which says **Log to the console** in case you see different log options (that would basically be possible when you have some identifier with the name log.

Click Enter.

[image: console.log() typed automatically!]

The intellisense will do its job!

Answer (score 12):

clg + tab

or as mentioned above,

log + enter (second option in dropdown)

This is an old question, but I hope is useful to some one else.

Comment: clg + tab gives `ChannelMergerNode` for me!

Comment: I think you need  to edit your keybindings as mentioned in the answers above ;)

Answer (score 9):

In case anybody is interested in putting the currently selected text into the `console.log()` statement:

```
{
    "key": "cmd+shift+l",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "console.log(${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}$1)$0;"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome!

Answer (score 9):

Type 'clg' then hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, it will auto complete to `console.log()`.
For this you only need to install an extension i.e. JavaScript (ES6) code snippets.

Comment: Also 'cwa' for console.warn()

Answer (score 8):

**Printing the value of a variable is very simple, but also something very repeatedly & frequently needed and done, so it necessitates the quickest of the shortcuts!**

So I recommend another solution in which you don't even need to select anything. You also neither need to copy/paste the variable's name, nor need to type in a snippet's prefix. **And it works for all languages too, with only a single hotkey! :)** (thanks to the vscode's "when" expressions)

- Here's a preview of how it works in action:

[image]

- Here are the steps you have to take to install it:

  1. Install the [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) extension from the extension store.
  2. Open the `settings.json` file of your vscode (*in case you don't know how, hit <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + p</kbd>. This will open up a command palette at the top. Write "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)" in it, and hit enter!*) then add the below item to it (will be explained):

```
  // generating a print statement of the current word on the next line, in different languages
  "multiCommand.commands": [
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.jsGeneratePrint",
      "sequence": [
        "editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch",
        "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
        "editor.action.insertLineAfter",
        {
          "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
            "snippet": "console.log(\"$CLIPBOARD: \", $CLIPBOARD);"
          }
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.javaGeneratePrint",
      "sequence": [
        "editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch",
        "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
        "editor.action.insertLineAfter",
        {
          "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
            "snippet": "System.out.println(\"$CLIPBOARD: \" + $CLIPBOARD);"
          }
        },
      ]
    },
  ],
```

4. Now open the `keybindings.json` file (*Write this in the command palette: "Preferences: Open keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)"*) and add the below items to it (will be explained):

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+b",
        "command": "multiCommand.jsGeneratePrint",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == javascript"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+b",
        "command": "multiCommand.javaGeneratePrint",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'java'"
    }
```

And voila!, we're done. Now, just put the pointer on a variable's name and hit the <kbd>ctrl+b</kbd> (I'm comfortable with <kbd>ctrl+b</kbd>, but you can change it as you prefer).

- Here's how it works (for the curious) :

  - *The first snippet above*: We created a "compound command" (thanks to the "multi-command" extension) which simply means a "sequence of multiple commands together as a new command". The sequence we have used is: 1. Select the current word which the pointer is at, 2. copy it to the clipboard, 3. go to the next line, 4. generate the print statement using the word already copied to the clipboard. and Voila! NOTICE however that we have to define one of these compound commands per each language, as different programming languages differ in how they print!
  - *The second snippet above*: We create *"two different hotkeys, but with the same key combinations"*. Most importantly they're different in their "where" conditions(in which we have specified the language of the code "where" this hotkey must work in), and then we add each of the compound commands to its own hotkey.

You can extend this method to cover any other languages as well, by just repeating the same pattern (It can also be extended in other ways, but I won't make this answer any longer). Hope that'll save you some time. :)

Comment: as for my use case, its better to remove the first element in sequence array. "editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch" need to be removed

Answer (score 8):

Make your own snippets in 3 easy steps.

1. Select `Configure User Snippets` from the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>)

   [image: configure snippets]
2. Select `Global Snippet` or `Snippets for <your-project>`

[image: select where to save snippets]

3. Edit the file, Save and Profit!

```json
{
  "consoleLog": {
    "prefix": "clg",
    "body": "console.log(${1:object});",
    "description": "Displays a message in the console"
  },
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't know what extension I'm using but I simply type log and hit tab to autocomplete console.log(); placing the cursor between the braces.

Answer (score 7):

The fastest way is:

Press <kbd>l</kbd> and select `log` in pop-up list

[image: console.log shortcut visual studio code]

Now, always when you press <kbd>l</kbd>, you just need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to `console.log()`

[image: console.log shortcut visual studio code]

Answer (score 5):

#### BEST COMBO

I learned the first feature of [Turbo Console Log](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChakrounAnas.turbo-console-log) (II, III, IV were not useful for me).

Then added this snippet, that is perfectly fitting to the Turbo Console Log:

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+l",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorHasSelection",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "console.log('$1')"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a better solution

```
{
        "key": "cmd+shift+c",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
        "args": {
            "snippet": "console.log('${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}', $TM_SELECTED_TEXT$1);"
        }
    }
```

Comment: And if I want console log to appear one line under the selected text? Could this be done with a snippet?

Answer (score 2):

The below one is currently selected text with single quotes. Hope it helps

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults
[{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+c",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "console.log('${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}$1')$2;"
    }

}]
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

just install this extension..
select any variable press ctrl shift l...boom dome

Comment: that works really great and is simple to install

Answer (score 1):

Install **ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL** extension and then type `clg + Enter/Return key`  for `console.log()`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can create a function easy to write that invokes the console.log and then just call that function.

```
 var a = funtion (x) {console.log(x)}
 a(2*2);        //prints 4
```

Comment: This is not answering the OP's question as this would have to be imported over every project, and is just a straight up nuisance. Having an inbuilt keybind is definitely they way to go here

Answer (score 0):

I use autohotkey to achieve the same effect,
Simply type "cc" then space, and it will output a console log. Haven't tried snippets, not sure how this compares

```
; vscode
#IfWinActive ahk_exe Code.exe

    SetTitleMatchMode 2

    ; Move by word - Backwards
    Capslock & d:: Send ^+k
    ::cc::console.log("test321:" {+}){left}
    ::cl::logger.info("test321:" {+}){left}
    ::cd::logger.debug("test321:" {+}){left}
    ::ss::JSON.stringify(test, null, 2){ctrl down}{left 3}{ctrl up}

#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, if you're using VSCode, is to use the **Turbo Console Log** extension which not only enables the Shortcut, but also smartly inserts custom text depending on your selected text. You can adjust it's settings to also log the file name/line number:

[GIF Showing functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ6TG.gif)

Obviously, installing an extension is not the same as changing keyboard shortcuts, but it's a good option if you want functionality similar to @aderchox 's Answer

Answer (score 0):

Add this to a snippet file with `$0`:

```
"Print to console": {
    "scope": "javascript,typescript",
    "prefix": "cl",
    "body": [
        "console.log($0);",
    ],
    "description": "Log output to console"
}
```

It seems `$0` is a better approach to auto focus to that area. If you use `$1` instead of `$0`, autocomplete doesn't work when you want to type something between parentheses (for example a variable name).

I wanted to say that in a comment but comments are unavailable for me.

Answer (score 0):

in vs code press ctrl+shift+P or from view menu click command palette
then click snippets: configure user snippets
next click javascript
and edit javascript.json to below code

```
{
"Print to console": {
    "prefix": "log",
    "body": [
        "console.log('$1');",
        "$2"
    ],
    "description": "Log output to console"
}
```

}

finally in js function write log and press tab key and select 'Print to console'

Answer (score 0):

With the **Stable Build v1.77 (March 2023)**, there is a new built-in command;
**runCommands** // run one or more commands in sequence

If you want to just bind a keyboard shortcut to create a console log statement with selected text, you can do the following:

By pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> , first it will copy the selected text, then insert a line after the selected text line, then output the console log statement with the selected text as a text in the left-side and as a value in the right-side.

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+l",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
            "editor.action.insertLineAfter",
            {
                "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
                "args": {
                    "snippet": "console.log('${CLIPBOARD}: ' + ${CLIPBOARD});"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

1. *File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts*
2. Above the search bar on the right you'll see this icon [image] Click on it. (*When hovered over it it says: Open keyboard shortcuts (JSON)*
3. Add this to the JSON settings:

Answer (score -1):

Type `co` and hit <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>enter</kbd>. 
Should work out of the box.

Comment: I think this might not be very reliable or is dependent on extensions. For me co+enter generates just the the text output and co+tab generates "confirm". Even "cons" + tab just generates "console".

Comment: converts to `console` for me