# Visual Studio Code Console log keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, console.log

As I was coding in Visual Studio code, I wondered if someone had created a tool for auto-completing the console log code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the shortcut in Visual Studio Code for console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40177331/what-is-the-shortcut-in-visual-studio-code-for-console-log)

Answer (score 0):

Sure enough, someone had written a workflow for it, and I'd have to say it's pretty phenomenal.

Since the author explains it so thoroughly and well, [here's the link to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67620196/12191011).