# Create a short cut for console log in vsode

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, webstorm

Not sure if this question belongs here so feel free to tell me where I should post it.

I wanna know if it's possible to have a short cut like in WebStorm where you can put the variable name and add a `.log` behind it click tab and it will turn it into a `console.log()`

For example:

```js
myVar.log
```

Will turn:

```js
console.log(myVar)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure about that, but surely you can define your own code snippets from Menu: Code>Preferences>Config User Snippets https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: you can by writing an extension with a `CompletionItemProvider`, but a snippet is a lot easier to do right now, you then type: `clogTABmyVar`

Comment: this has been asked about before but I'm too lazy to look up the correct dup target. I'd rather just refer you to https://stackoverflow.com/q/40177331/11107541.