# Visual Studio 2017 - How do I duplicate the current line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, copy, visual-studio-2017, code-duplication

I want to duplicate the current line to a new line below it. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203752/how-do-i-duplicate-a-line-or-selection-within-visual-studio-code) post but I can't find the option they're talking about (`editor.action.copyLinesDownAction`) in options > keyboard.

How do we do this in 2017?

Comment: Is CTRL + D not working?

Comment: No sir. Doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: You can try reset your settings `Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all setting`  (Do not forget to take a backup of your current settings)

Comment: Tried that too, didn't work. I'm in Microsoft Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code if that helps. Also I found an extension that does it for me. Found it in the search bar in `...extensions and plugins`. I just searched "duplicate" and installed the first one, bound it to `alt+d` and it's all good now : ). Thanks for your help though

Comment: I've even assigned "Edit.Duplicate" command to Ctrl+D (Global) and it still doesn't do anything - either it doesn't work or it does something else I'm not clear about

Comment: I have an install that has been upgraded several times over the years. Edit.Duplicate isn't an option in the Show Commands of Customize->Keyboard. Frustrating because on my main machine that is newer and has a fresh install the option is there and is mapped to Ctrl+D in the Text Editor. Both machines have the same version of VS installed.

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure if this is a new feature from one of the updates but the following key combination works for me in VS 2017 (v 15.7.3):

```
Ctrl + E,V
```

This duplicates the current line that the cursor is on or it will duplicate any selected text and you won't lose the contents stored in the clipboard.
I have not tried remapping that command to a different key combination.

Comment: Worked for me! Great tip!

Answer (score 8):

Found an extension that does this [right here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ctlajoie.DuplicateSelection). Hope this helps people.

Answer (score 7):

Click anywhere on the line you want to duplicate (do not select the text), press Ctrl+C, and press Ctrl+V to create the duplicated line. You can duplicate that line to anywhere now, not just to next line and it will insert the line above the selected line. e.g.

```
427    string foo = "text";
428
429        string bar = "other";
```

Click anywhere on line 427 and press Ctrl+C.
Click on line 429 and press Ctrl+V

```
427    string foo = "text";
428
429    string foo = "text";
430        string bar = "other";
```

Comment: What you describe is "copy & paste", not true "duplicate line". It is hard to understand why it is doesn't exist in VS

Comment: Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V is easy to remember. Thanks!