# Visual Studio Code: duplicate a line shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I am new to Visual Studio Code. I want to know how to duplicate a line using a *keyboard shortcut*.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Also discussed here: [How do I duplicate a line or selection within Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203752/how-do-i-duplicate-a-line-or-selection-within-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 11):

In Visual Studio Code you can perform the "Copy line down/up" action. The keyboard shortcut varies depending on your operating system.

The defaults for each os are as follows.

1. Windows

   <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>
2. Macos

   <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>
3. Linux

   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>

**Note**: This shortcut will also copy multi-line selections up and down as in Sublime but when a subset of a line is selected the entire line is copied.

Comment: The ctrl + alt + shift + Up/Down arrows is not working on linux for Vs Code latest version 1.38.0