# Visual studio shortcuts (Duplication)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can someone tell me how to duplicate the line I am on as most of the people do in visual studio code and list for me some shortcuts or where I can see them?/.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: By default, if you copy without having anything selected, it will copy the entire line including its linebreak, so if you directly paste on the same line it will duplicate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I duplicate a line or selection within Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203752/how-do-i-duplicate-a-line-or-selection-within-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Is your question about `visual studio`  or `visual studio code`?  The title and the tag says `visual studio`  the question says `visual studio code`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate line (down/up)
Visual Studio Code.

Windows:

**Shift+ Alt + ↓ or Shift+ Alt + ↑**

Shortcuts for [Win](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf)

---

Mac:

**Shift + Option + ↓ or Shift +Option + ↑**

Shortcuts for [Mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf)

---

Linux:

**Ctrl+Shift+Alt+↓ or Ctrl+Shift+Alt+↑**

Shortcuts for [Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf)

(some distros You need use Numpad arrows)

Comment: Thank you very much that will save me a lot of time.

Comment: It's my pleasure;-) You 're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can press ctrl+d to duplicate your current line.