# VS Code Duplicate Line hotkey does not work in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint

I've recently migrated from windows to Linux (specifically Linux Mint Cinnamon) and in VS Code I'm used to being able to Copy Line up or down via this hotkey: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>

I looked up the equivalent in Linux and found this helpful [Stack Overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203752/how-do-i-duplicate-a-line-or-selection-within-visual-studio-code) stating I should use the following for Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>

However, when I try and use this, nothing happens. The keybind appears to do nothing.

I've tried rebinding the keys to alternatives and this works, but they aren't as comfortable to press as the default. Is there anything I can do to use the default linux keybinds? Why do these defaults not work for Linux Mint?

Comment: check your system / desktop environment keybindings to see if there's anything there using that keybinding already.

Comment: How do I check these keybinds on Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution from [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/hyldry/vscode_shortcut_not_working_on_cinnamon/) running:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.wm move-to-workspace-up []

gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.wm move-to-workspace-down []
```

removes the existing keybinds, allowing the default linux keybinds to work.